# Access violation writing location 0x01140000

Tags: c, file, directory, access-violation

I'm relatively new to C and I'm stuck on a problem. I want to list through given directory and to search through all files or subdirectories, and to write down the names of the files and when was the last access to it. But everytime after the sprintf_s() it gives me Access violation.I think it has something to do with my pointer as an argument in the recursive function.
So this is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<direct.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1

bool ListFromDirectory(const char* sDir) {//recursive functions for listing through the directory
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fdFile;
    HANDLE hFind = NULL;

    char sPath[2048];

    //Specify a file mask. *.*
     sprintf_s(sPath, "%s\\*.*", sDir);
    if ((hFind = FindFirstFile(sPath, &fdFile)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Path not found: [%s]\n", sDir);
        return false;
    }

    do
    {
        //Find first file will always return "."
        //    and ".." as the first two directories.
        if (strcmp(fdFile.cFileName, ".") != 0
            && strcmp(fdFile.cFileName, "..") != 0)
        {
            LPSYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime;

            //Is the entity a File or Folder?
            if (fdFile.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                printf("Directory: %s\n", sPath);
                ListFromDirectory(sPath);
            }
            else {
                printf("File: %ls\n", fdFile.cFileName);
                FILETIME localFiletime;
                if (FileTimeToLocalFileTime(&fdFile.ftLastWriteTime, &localFiletime)) {
                    SYSTEMTIME sysTime;
                    if (FileTimeToSystemTime(&localFiletime, &sysTime)) {
                        printf("%ls is last modified at %.2d-%.2d-%4d %.2d:%.2d:%.2d\n",
                            fdFile.cFileName,                            
                            sysTime.wMonth, sysTime.wDay, sysTime.wYear,
                            sysTime.wHour, sysTime.wMinute, sysTime.wSecond);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &fdFile)); //Find the next file.

    FindClose(hFind);

    return true;
}
int main() {
    char c[12] = "E:\\Windows\\";
    ListFromDirectory(c);
    return 0;
}
```

> The error after sprintf_s(): Exception thrown at 0x7A85EF8C (ucrtbased.dll): 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00760000.

Answer (score 1):

You have overlooked the compiler warnings and the man page for [`sprintf_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-s-sprintf-s-l-swprintf-s-swprintf-s-l?view=msvc-170) which states that you need to pass a buffer size, so

```
sprintf_s(sPath, "%s\\*.*", sDir);
```

should be

```
sprintf_s(sPath, sizeof sPath, "%s\\*.*", sDir);
```

The compiler is also giving a lot of warnings about the type specifiers you use in format strings.